# git: permissions error after git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had a git installation working fine, using a networked computer as a remote.  However, this computer developed a problem and I've tried to move my remote to bitbucket.org.  I believe I have most of it setup correctly, but I cannot perform a `git pull` without receiving the following error:

> fatal: failed to open 'equityChartLog.php': Permission denied

I have given 777 permissions to the entire directory as well as the .git directory.  I've deleted the file in question.  Nothing seems to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

The only thing I can think is that git is a different user than my login, but with 777 permissions I don't think it should matter.

Comment: You'd also see this error if another process has an open file handle to this file.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a new clone of the repo or even another machine?

Comment: I think I'm going to delete my .git folder and basically start over.  I did try this on another machine and didn't have the same error.